# T-Mobile REVVL 4+ Android phone constantly bleeping. Took phone out of wallet case & noise stopped. Think magnets?

Tags: audio, t-mobile

T-Mobile REVVL 4+ Android. Constantly bleeping start-up sound. Notifications turned off. Took the phone out of the wallet case & bleeping noise stopped.

Does anyone else have wallet magnets that cause their phone to make constant noise? Anything to do to the demagnetize problem so I can use the wallet for my phone?

Comment: I'm not sure about the magnet (unless the device supports a smart case), but probably the NFC feature detecting contactless cards in the wallet?

Comment: What magnets have you got in your wallet?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, its almost definitely detecting the credit/debit cards.

To stop it, turn off the NFC.

- Swipe the status bar down
- Scroll until you spot NFC.
- Press into turn it off.

If this solves it, then here are some solutions.

- Leave NFC off
- Put the phone in the other pocket
- Separate the phone from the cards with a metallic (slightly magnetic) film.
- The NFC detector is at the top of the phone, rotate the phone to increase the distance from the cards.